# CYPHER, NEO4J Returning couples of nodes that are connected by a relationship of type A and not by a relation of type B

Tags: database, neo4j, nosql, cypher

I am working on the Neo4j tutorial Movies database. 
I would like to make a query that returns the people that directed a movie but did not produced it.

In order to accomplish this I have used the query:

```
match (m:Movie)<-[:DIRECTED]-(p:Person)-[r]->(m) where type(r) <> 'PRODUCED' return p
```

Nevertheless, if I make it return * I still get these couples (person, movie) where the person not only directed and produced the film but also wrote it:

[In the image there is one of the not admissible couples that are returned by my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jioJq.png)

On the contrary, the query seems to successfully rule out all those couples that are with only the two relationships 'PRODUCED' and 'DIRECTED'.

Is there a way of writing this query so that I can rule out all these couples as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can use path pattern in `WHERE`:](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/#query-where-patterns)

```
match (m:Movie)<-[r:DIRECTED]-(p:Person) 
where not (p)-[:PRODUCED]->(m)
return m, p, r
```

Comment: This one works! Thank you! Could you also explain to me why mine does not work??